# Computing the normalization constants $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We know the following:
$z$ is a continuous variable, and $c$ is a binary variable
$$ z   \in [0,1]  $$
$$ c \in \{0,1\} $$
$$ p(c = 0) = 1/6 $$
$$ p(c = 1) = 5/6 $$
$$ p(z|c =0) = \alpha_0(1−z^2) $$
$$ p(z|c =1) = \alpha_1 (z^2 + z) $$

Given these, calculate the normalization constants $ \alpha_0 , \alpha_1 $.

I know that $ \int_0^1 p(z) dz = 1 $ must hold, and using the sum and product rules I get an equation containing only the normalization constants: $ 4\alpha_0 + 25\alpha_1 = 36 $ but I think I am missing something to calculate the exact values of the constants. This is my first question here, so please let me know if there's any problem with the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact $\int_0^1p(z|c=i)dz=1$ for each $i\in\{0,\,1\}$, so $\alpha_0=\frac{1}{\int_0^1(1-z^2)dz}=\frac32,\,\alpha_1=\frac{1}{\int_0^1(z+z^2)dz}=\frac65$. Hence $4\alpha_0+25\alpha_1=6+30=36$, as expected.

Comment: Now it is clear! Thank you so much!